# how to show facebook messanger plugin on website

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-messenger

I try running messenger plugin on my website. I added js sdk with messenger function but when I open the website a messenger plugin not shows me.

below is sdk:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId            : '**************',
      autoLogAppEvents : true,
      xfbml            : true,
      version          : 'v8.0'
    });
    
    FB.CustomerChat.showDialog();
    
  };
  
  (function(d, s, id) {
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
      js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
      js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk/xfbml.customerchat.js";
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

I use public domain with ssl and my domain it was added to setting app. What wrong I do?

Comment: Did you go through the troubleshooting tips already? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/discovery/facebook-chat-plugin#debug-tips

Comment: I forgot add my domain to whitelist. Now it works, thanks!